# App to adjust screen locking behavior on smartphone

Tags: android, lockscreen

I have a few apps that don't work the way they should when the screen is locked, most notably the gymboss interval timer: The app is supposed to beep every x seconds, but when the screen is locked the timer runs but there's no beep. I found no way in the settings to tell my phone to not lock the screen when the gymboss app is running. Is there another app that allows me to finetune the screen locking settings in such a way?

I'm using a fairphone with the fairphone OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions to that. The one I prefer is using **[Tasker](http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.dinglisch.android.taskerm)** – the most comprehensive automation tool available for Android, and supported by many addons/plugins. Using this tool, I do something similar for apps I use to "read stuff". While my usual screen-timeout is set to 30s, I increase it to 3 minutes whenever my RSS or eBook reader are running "in foreground". As soon as they are no longer, *Tasker* automatically reverts the timeout to its previous value (here: 30s).

What I just wrote refers to the screen *timeout* (i.e. how long it takes until it gets locked). If you instead want to disable the lock completely, *Tasker* can do that as well ("Disable Keyguard"). For a better fine-tuning, you can add the [Secure Settings](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.intangibleobject.securesettings.plugin) addon to the equation.

For more details and help on *Tasker* and its addons, you might wish to take a look into:

- [my collection of *Tasker* resources](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/resources_tasker)
- the [tasker tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/tasker/info) at our sister-site for Android

Surely, *Tasker* is not one of the "cheapest apps" for Android (~USD 5), but it's definitely worth its price – over at Android.SE we use to say, almost every second issue can be solved using this app :) There's a 7-day trial on their homepage if you first want to evaluate. Back then when I started with the app, it took me no more than 3 days to convince myself and buy it straight ahead :)